# How to change a selection of a POSIXct vector from YDM to YMD in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a large dataset with POSIXct datetimes in a YMD_HMS format. I however came to realize that some dates were entered in the database in a YDM_HMS format instead of YMD_HMS. This is visible in the density-plot below.
[image: datetimes]

The observations run in march and april, but somehow the first of April through the 12th of April have been wrongly added, and are therefore spread across the year. Obviously I want to change tose YDM's into YMD's, but I fail...

A reproducible example is this df:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), datetime = ymd_hms("2020-03-01 00:02:15",
                                                     "2020-03-25 01:03:33",
                                                     "2020-03-14 03:45:55",
                                                     "2020-01-04 05:37:27",
                                                     "2020-01-04 06:23:38",
                                                     "2020-04-12 09:09:43",
                                                     "2020-04-21 12:44:47",
                                                     "2020-02-04 17:38:52",
                                                     "2020-04-24 19:44:21",
                                                     "2020-04-28 21:49:34",
                                                     tz = "UTC"))
```

I made an extra vector containing the dates, so I can target the faulty observations easily:

`df$date <- as.Date(df$datetime)`

Then I thought I could easily use an `ifelse()`. The condition is the selection of dates which are wrong, the TRUE action is to cooerce it into character and then into ydm_hms, the FALSE action is to maintain datetime. This fails...

```
df <- df %>%
   ifelse(date %in% c("2020-01-04", "2020-02-04"), ydm_hms(as.character(datetime), tz = "UTC"), datetime)
Error in ifelse(., date %in% c("2020-01-04", "2020-02-04"), ydm_hms(as.character(datetime),  : 
  unused argument (datetime)
```

Adding `mutate()` like this `df <- df %>% mutate(datetime = ifelse(date %in% c("2020-01-04", "2020-02-04"), ydm_hms(as.character(datetime), tz = "UTC"), datetime))` doesn't maintain a POSIXct  format for the datetime-vector:

```
> df
   id   datetime       date
1   1 1583020935 2020-03-01
2   2 1585098213 2020-03-25
3   3 1584157555 2020-03-14
4   4 1578116247 2020-01-04
5   5 1578119018 2020-01-04
6   6 1586682583 2020-04-12
7   7 1587473087 2020-04-21
8   8 1580837932 2020-02-04
9   9 1587757461 2020-04-24
10 10 1588110574 2020-04-28
```

Question: how do I get this output:

```
   id            datetime
1   1 2020-03-01 00:02:15
2   2 2020-03-25 01:03:33
3   3 2020-03-14 03:45:55
4   4 2020-04-01 05:37:27
5   5 2020-04-01 06:23:38
6   6 2020-04-12 09:09:43
7   7 2020-04-21 12:44:47
8   8 2020-04-02 17:38:52
9   9 2020-04-24 19:44:21
10 10 2020-04-28 21:49:34
```

Comment: `df$datetime[!month(df$datetime) %in% 3:4] <- ydm_hms(as.character(df$datetime[!month(df$datetime) %in% 3:4]), tz = "UTC")`

Comment: The suggestion of @Roland doesn't change anything in my df...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `ifelse`, we can use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(datetime = replace(datetime, date %in% as.Date(c("2020-01-04", "2020-02-04")),
      ydm_hms(as.character(datetime[date %in% as.Date(c("2020-01-04", "2020-02-04"))]), tz = "UTC") ))

df
#   id            datetime       date
#1   1 2020-03-01 00:02:15 2020-03-01
#2   2 2020-03-25 01:03:33 2020-03-25
#3   3 2020-03-14 03:45:55 2020-03-14
#4   4 2020-04-01 05:37:27 2020-01-04
#5   5 2020-04-01 06:23:38 2020-01-04
#6   6 2020-04-12 09:09:43 2020-04-12
#7   7 2020-04-21 12:44:47 2020-04-21
#8   8 2020-04-02 17:38:52 2020-02-04
#9   9 2020-04-24 19:44:21 2020-04-24
#10 10 2020-04-28 21:49:34 2020-04-28
```

---

Or another option with `rowwise`

```
df %>% 
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(datetime = if(date %in% 
         as.Date(c("2020-01-04", "2020-02-04"))) ydm_hms(datetime, tz = "UTC") else datetime)
```

---

Or with `case_when` after interchanging the month, day with `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(datetime = ymd_hms(case_when(date %in% 
      as.Date(c("2020-01-04", "2020-02-04")) ~ 
           str_replace(datetime, '-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})', '-\\2-\\1'), TRUE ~ as.character(datetime))))
#  id            datetime       date
#1   1 2020-03-01 00:02:15 2020-03-01
#2   2 2020-03-25 01:03:33 2020-03-25
#3   3 2020-03-14 03:45:55 2020-03-14
#4   4 2020-04-01 05:37:27 2020-01-04
#5   5 2020-04-01 06:23:38 2020-01-04
#6   6 2020-04-12 09:09:43 2020-04-12
#7   7 2020-04-21 12:44:47 2020-04-21
#8   8 2020-04-02 17:38:52 2020-02-04
#9   9 2020-04-24 19:44:21 2020-04-24
#10 10 2020-04-28 21:49:34 2020-04-28
```

NOTE: All three solutions work

Comment: This doesn't work, and throws this error:
```
Warning message:
 5 failed to parse. 
```

Comment: @JohanVos try with `replace`

Comment: this doesn't throw an error anymore, but doesn't change anything in the df either...

Comment: @JohanVos The reason is that 'date %in%` is not working.  It should be `as.Date(c('''`

Comment: @JohanVos please check the output

Comment: After running an update on my packages it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index for the rows where date is one of `c("2020-01-04", "2020-02-04")` and change those dates with  `ydm_hms`.

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$datetime)
inds <- df$date %in% as.Date(c("2020-01-04", "2020-02-04"))
df$datetime[inds] <- lubridate::ydm_hms(df$datetime[inds])

df
#   id            datetime       date
#1   1 2020-03-01 00:02:15 2020-03-01
#2   2 2020-03-25 01:03:33 2020-03-25
#3   3 2020-03-14 03:45:55 2020-03-14
#4   4 2020-04-01 05:37:27 2020-01-04
#5   5 2020-04-01 06:23:38 2020-01-04
#6   6 2020-04-12 09:09:43 2020-04-12
#7   7 2020-04-21 12:44:47 2020-04-21
#8   8 2020-04-02 17:38:52 2020-02-04
#9   9 2020-04-24 19:44:21 2020-04-24
#10 10 2020-04-28 21:49:34 2020-04-28
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but the last line doesn't change my df at all. I don't get the output you get :(

Comment: Are you testing this on the data shared or on your real data? Does it work for you for the data that you have shared?

Comment: That's weird. I just restarted R and tried it again and it works for me, same as shown in my answer. Can you do the same and try again? Probably add `tz = 'UTC'` (don't know if it matters). `df$datetime[inds] <- lubridate::ydm_hms(df$datetime[inds], tz = 'UTC')`

Comment: After running an update on my packages it worked just fine.